# Replace specific cell values if value is broken

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel sheet with broken characters in some values

sample:

```
Email               Name
sample@gmail.com    Sample Name
sample2@gmail.com   Ð¸Ð³Ð¾Ñ€ÑŒ
```

```
from ftfy import fix_encoding
import pandas as pd

def FixExcelFile():
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")])
    if filepath:
        xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(filepath)
        sheet_name = xlsx.sheet_names[0]
        sheet = xlsx.parse(sheet_name)
        name_values = sheet['Name'].values
        for idx, value in enumerate(name_values):
            if isinstance(value, str):
                fixedvalue = fix_encoding(value)
                if fixedvalue != value:
                    print(value + " --> " + fixedvalue)
```

Console output is

`Ð¸Ð³Ð¾Ñ€ÑŒ Ñ€ --> игорь`

My questions now is, how do I replace the values in the spreadsheet itself?

Comment: did you try `sheet['Name'].values[idx] = fixedvalue` ?

Comment: This replaces the value in the array, unfortunately not in the spreadsheet

Comment: did you save it back in file ?

Comment: Well no, this was my question, I don't know how to properly save it back to the file

Comment: see documentation for [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas-excelwriter)